# @Proxy in Hibernate Annotation

Tags: hibernate, proxy

what is@Proxy(lazy=false) means in hibernate annotation?

```
   @Entity
@Table(name="addresses")
@Proxy(lazy=false)
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="adid")
    private int adid;

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;
//Constructor, getter and setter methods
}
```

please any one explain me the concept

Answer (score 1):

@Proxy(lazy=false) will just disable the default lazy loading. It means that you will always get the initialized entity whenever this entity is being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through official Doc @ https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-pojo-final